# Detect when ethernet cable is plugged

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, ethernet

I'm trying to detect when an Ethernet cable is plugged-in or unplugged but i have some probleme and i don't know if i'm doing this good or not.

I'm using `NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged` 
to detect when the network change

and then `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` for checking if Ethernet connexion is available or not with the property `.OperationalStatus`.

But when i search for the Ethernet connexion in all the network interfaces, it return me what i'm looking for, but it **always return me the Bluetooth connection** with it.

Here is the code :

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged += new NetworkAddressChangedEventHandler(AddressChangedCallback);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void AddressChangedCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
    foreach (NetworkInterface myInterface in adapters)
    {
        //if (n.Description.ToLower().Contains("ethernet")){
        //if (n.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString().ToLower().Contains("ethernet")){

        IPInterfaceProperties properties = n.GetIPProperties();
        if (myInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myInterface.Description + " ........... :  " + myInterface.OperationalStatus);
            Console.WriteLine("NetworkInterfaceType : " + myInterface.NetworkInterfaceType);
        }
    }
}
```

At the beginning, i was trying to check the name of the connection and looks if contains the "Ethernet" word, but it appears (if i'm not wrong) sometimes the connection name does not contain "Ethernet".

Do you have some tips for always bring the good connection (without the bluetooth)?
Am i wrong in my approach?

---

I'm testing it on a Surface Pro 3... but maybe i have the Bluetooth problem because of that?
Despite that, i need it to work even on device like this.

Comment: Bluetooth devices can provide many services, one of which *is* network connectivity. If the driver presents the network interface as an Ethernet card, then to the OS it's an Ethernet card.

Comment: Why do you specifically want to know whether there is an unplugged cable? What do you plan to do with this information?

Comment: @Tragedian have to turn wifi on when the cable is unplugged and turn it off when the cable is connected

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ok thanks, I thought about it but if it's true, i think this isn't the good way to check if the cable is plugged

Comment: If your Bluetooh connection never changes, you could just hardcode a filter for it, and detects if there is other connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This links shows how to do it with Powershell, but one of the cases uses WMI.

http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/04/04/pstip-detecting-wi-fi-adapters/

And this links shows a interesting property that can help sometimes:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217(v=vs.85).aspx

> GatewayCostMetric
>
> Data type: uint16 array
>
> Access type: Read-only Array
>
> of integer cost metric values (ranging from 1 to 9999) to be used in
> calculating the fastest, most reliable, or least resource-intensive
> routes. This argument has a one-to-one correspondence with the
> DefaultIPGateway property.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by checking its operational status as:

```
foreach (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface net in System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
     if (net.OperationalStatus == 
        System.Net.NetworkInformation.OperationalStatus.Up)
           Console.WriteLine("N/w connected");
     else
           Console.WriteLine("N/w not connected");
}
```

Comment: Hi ! It was 2 years ago and i don't remember what i ended up doing but it wasn't far from that. I probably used some WMI related functionnalities with System.Net.NetworkInformation to check the connection. I worked fine and i could check from what network adapter the connections were from and it helped me a lot. I think Daniel Frederico Lins Leite response helped me a lot to resolve the problem.

Comment: Hi, I just came across this post when I was working recently and found same issue. I could find resolution and therefore, wish to share. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The below function returns true when the ethernet is connected. Returns false if ethernet is not connected or even if WiFi is connected.

```
 public bool isEthernetConnected() {
            foreach (NetworkInterface net in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
                if (net.OperationalStatus ==
                   OperationalStatus.Up)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected "+ net.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString());   
                    if (net.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString().Contains("Loopback") || net.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString().Contains("Wireless80211"))
                        continue;
                    else if (net.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString().Contains("Ethernet"))
                        return true;
                                     
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ethernet not connected");                    
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```