# Ethernet cable disconnection detection in C#

Tags: c#, ethernet

I need to detect the Ethernet cable disconnection in the system, for the same I'm using the following code to detect the changes in all the networks available in the system.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace Examples.Net.AddressChanges
{
    public class NetworkingExample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged += new
            NetworkAddressChangedEventHandler(AddressChangedCallback);
            Console.WriteLine("Listening for address changes. Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void AddressChangedCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
            foreach (NetworkInterface n in adapters)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("   {0} is {1}", n.Name, n.OperationalStatus);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My requirement, is to run a set of code when the "operational status" of "Ethernet" is "down" and another set of code when the "operational status" of "Ethernet" is "Up".

I'm pretty new to this, so I'm not able to use the operational status to do the required programming.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Did you check this question [Detect when ethernet cable is plugged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884367/detect-when-ethernet-cable-is-plugged) ?

Comment: What's the overall objective? Bearing in mind that the status of an ethernet or other network connection, however up to date it may be, does not tell you anything about your code's ability to do something *using* the network in the immediate future.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to check if your program has access to the internet/network? This seems like a case of [The XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What _exactly_ are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Damien My objective is sending and receiving data from a remote server (PLC) using Ethernet connection. I need to stop execution of this block of code when the ethernet cable is disconnected.

Comment: You mean, when you have no connection to the server? What good is the ethernet cable if your network is still down? The thing is that if you ask "How do I do X", we can only answer "How to do X", if at all possible. But if you really want to do Y, like detect when you have no possibility of reaching a particular server, then you need to ask about that instead. And in this case, I suspect the answer to Y is easier to deal with than X. So ask about what your end goal is, not about your current solution to that end goal. Perhaps there is a different solution that is easier.